# No Outlets for 2nd storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have setup a second storyboard in my app for iPhone 5.  I looked into constraints and autolayout and etc but could not find a viable solution for my app.  The problem is my background image is linked to quite a lot of UILabels I have hence when resizing to iPhone 5 although the image is expanded the labels are in the wrong place.  The constraints fix them to a place but it is no longer in the right position according to the background image.

Hence I have now set up another storyboard and I'm wanting to connect by buttons etc to outlets as I have in my original storyboard, but there are NO outlets to select in the new storyboard.  How do I add them / where can I find them?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please only ask one question per... well, question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't suggest to use the Autolayout if the user interface in not complicated and has autorotation with layout.

You can disable the Autolayout and use standart Autoresizing mask

[image]

2) You will have access to outlets only when you set the Custom Class to the ViewController in the Interface Builder.

Adopting storyboards - the best guide
http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351707109

Comment: "[I]t is not good practice to have 2 storyboards for 1 project for the same device...." This seems to me to be an opinion that is unsupported by any facts. I would argue that the opposite is true for large projects. For example, imagine trying to merge commits of a single, huge storyboard on a 20-developer team.